# android How to run simple clock in android

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I used script to create simple clock. but when i execute the program RUN() function is working but when I assign any value to TextView it show Unfortunately error in android device . please help me to resolve the problem. 
Here is my code

```
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
MyTimerTask mytask=new MyTimerTask();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(mytask, 3000, 1000);


class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

public void run() {
      tv.setText("Testing"); //(WHEN THIS LINE WILL BE COMMENT 
                                     //IT IS RUNNING   PROPERLY BUT WHEN 
                                     //I SHOW THIS LINE IT SHOW ERROR)
}
}
```

Comment: u can use chronometer

Comment: google it once or look at this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ChronometerDemo.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow logcat, it should tell you something along the lines of "You can't change the text from a seperate thread". When you're using a timer, you're doing just that. You need to post the textview to add it to the message queue, which will then run the Runnable on the UI thread, so simply replacing

```
tv.setText("Testing");
```

with

```
tv.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            tv.setText("Testing");
    }
});
```

should work fine.